# How to transform a vertex-labeled graph to another while keeping its connectivity and maximum degree during the transformation.

Tags: graph-theory

There are two **connected**, **vertex-labeled**, **undirected** graph $G$ and $G^*$,
where

1. $V(G)$ = $V(G^*)$, all nodes are labeled;
2. $\triangle (G) \leq k$, $\triangle (G^*) \leq k$, where $k>2$;

I want to *move/add/delete* the edges of $G$ to transform it to $G^*$,
while all the interim graphs must be connected and its maximum degree must not exceed $k$.

An example is shown in the following figure.

[image: e.g.]

> It is easy to transform such a graph (denoted as $G$) to a ring (denoted as $R(G)$ via *deleting/adding* edges, and such an transformation is always reversible.
>
> So a feasible solution (no optimal) is: $G$ --> $R(G)$ --> $R(G^*)$ --> $G^*$.

How to find more *optimal* solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining connectedness and the maximal degree makes this problem *harder* than the problem of computing graph edit distance.  (Excluding vertex insertion/deletion is not significant.)  Merely computing the graph edit distance between two graphs is NP-hard.

Papers:

- [Comparing Stars: On Approximating Graph Edit Distance](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD4QFjAD&url=http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~atung/publication/vldb09graphedit.pdf&ei=6WgpU4foKM202AWw5IAw&usg=AFQjCNG1TJZhmie3EYGIh8vnmaJU3BGH7Q&sig2=0Rp4Oh_Cv4OQrBczaeD8Hg&cad=rja)
- [Approximate graph edit distance computation by means of bipartite
  graph matching](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S026288560800084X)
- [A survey of graph edit distance](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnlpr-web.ia.ac.cn%2F2010papers%2F%25E5%25BC%2580%25E6%2594%25BE%25E8%25AF%25BE%25E9%25A2%2598%2F%25E5%259B%25BD%25E9%2599%2585%25E5%2588%258A%25E7%2589%25A9%2FXinbo%2520Gao%2C%2520A%2520survey%2520of%2520graph%2520edit%2520distance.pdf&ei=7Gk0UoflMofS0QXXgoDoBg&usg=AFQjCNGu8uvZ9N6mW_rZCPBlINnZFOh_1g&sig2=aFjsHpKyFsVtRjP5tlQkww&bvm=bv.52164340,d.d2k)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a little difference from GED since no isomorphic problem is considered here.

Comment: @rossini:  In thinking about the problem, there is an isomorphism problem (unfortunately, it's wrapped in an implicit matching problem) -- given two graphs is there a connected edge subset that is isomorphic between them?  Your connectivity requirement places a lower bound on the intermediate graphs.  If $G$ and $G^*$ can both be deleted to the same connected subset of edges, then you have a path.  I don't even know how to answer that decision problem in PTIME.